# How do I specify that a VB6 form is not resizable?

Tags: vb6

How do I prevent the user from resizing form dialogues in VB6? The dialogues are small and simple and resizing them serves no purpose, so I'd prefer to prevent it than write code to handle it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the `BorderStyle` of the form to either **"Fixed Single"** (`vbFixedSingle`) or **"Fixed Dialog"** (`vbFixedDouble`) at design-time. Either of these will prevent the user from resizing the form.

> **Fixed Single** provides a Control-menu box, title bar, Maximize
>   button, and Minimize button. The form
>   will still be resizable using the
>   Maximize and Minimize buttons, but not
>   by dragging the edges of the window.
>
> **Fixed Dialog** provides a Control-menu box and title bar, but
>   eliminates the Maximize and Minimize
>   buttons. It is therefore not resizable
>   at all. (Also note that a form that
>   contains a menu cannot be displayed as
>   a Fixed Dialog and is automatically
>   changed to the Fixed Single border
>   style.)

See also the relevant MSDN entry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245047(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Select as BorderStyle "Fixed Single"

Answer (score 2):

Change the BorderStyle.  Toolbox, Fixed dialog or property window should do it I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the BorderStyle of the form to "Fixed Single" and If you want to have a minimizable form , set MinButton property to "True".

Answer (score 0):

form border options available in vb6 are

```
me.BorderStyle = 0 ' – None
me.Appearance = 0 '– Flat
me.BorderStyle = 1 '– Fixed Single
me. Appearance = 1 '– 3D
me.BorderStyle = 1 '– Fixed Single
```